# Got "lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH" on Specific device after android 12 update

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, android-permissions, android-12

So i have an application that connect to bluetooth printer. It is fine and running on all devices except these devices:

- Xiaomi redmi note 10 Pro (Updated to android 12 with MIUI 13.0.1)
- Oppo Reno 5 4G (model: CPH2159) (Updated to android 12 with Color Os 13)

Regarding [Google developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher), android 12 using these three permission

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
```

but when i tried to connect on my printer, i got this error that makes me pulls my hair out.

```
2022-03-21 09:23:49.039 29022-29206/com.xxxx.xxxxx E/BThermalPrinterPlugin: UID 10324 / PID 29022 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH
    java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10324 / PID 29022 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothSocketManager$Stub$Proxy.connectSocket(IBluetoothSocketManager.java:227)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:404)
        at id.kakzaki.blue_thermal_printer.BlueThermalPrinterPlugin.lambda$connect$1$id-kakzaki-blue_thermal_printer-BlueThermalPrinterPlugin(BlueThermalPrinterPlugin.java:544)
        at id.kakzaki.blue_thermal_printer.BlueThermalPrinterPlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

is this sort of ROM/platform/device specific problem. android.permission.BLUETOOTH supposed to be used on android 11 and below because android 12 and above replaces it with android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, right? then why i got those specific device errors in the first place?

i have tried in Samsung A52 with android 12 and got no problem at all.

i have added necessary permission on manifest

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

and runtime permission request

```
        var perm = arrayListOf(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
        )
        //permission
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { //  >= android 12
                perm.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                perm.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                perm.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                    perm.toTypedArray(), ActivityBase.REQ_PERM
                )
            }
```

Comment: Having the same problem on MIUI 13.0.3.  Is working fine for Samsung Galaxy phones on Android 12.

Comment: how is this going

Comment: @alkaaf hey did you find any fix, getting similar issue

Comment: I have same problem on: Redmi Note 10, POCO X3 Pro, Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite, Motorola moto g(30). Did you report the problem to Xiaomi?

Comment: i decided to use usb connection as a solution in my case and put bluetooth problems into stuck. there is an answer using tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion". that is worth to try. for now, looks like the problem already fixed by the rom update.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you already found, Xiaomi seems to have an incorrect implementation of the Bluetooth spec.

I had the same problem as you do and solved it declaring *android.permission.BLUETOOTH* in AndroidManifest.xml, even for Android 12.

So, instead of adding the following line, which the documentation suggests:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
             android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

I had to add the *tools:remove* attribute because the Bluetooth library I was using was adding the maxSdkVersion attribute already. So it was being included in my merged manifest even if I didn't add it myself.

Also note that adding this permission in the manifest didn't cause any further problems or permission prompts on other Android 12 devices like Samsung.

Comment: Does remove maxSdkVersion still work for Android 11 and earlier devices?

Comment: Yes, versions earlier than sdk 31 (Android 12) in fact need the line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"> to be present. What the tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"  does is leave this line for sdk 31 as well.

Comment: This seems to be the work-around for this issue. 
Thanks @ManuelB.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a Xiaomi/MIUI issues. To make it work, you can use with `android:targetSdkVersion="30"` and not with `android:targetSdkVersion="31"`.

Answer (score -3):

The following code snippet demonstrates how to declare Bluetooth-related permissions in your app if it targets Android 12 or higher:

```
<manifest>
<!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
     If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
     location information, you can strongly assert that your app
     doesn't derive physical location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
     devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

<!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
     devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<!-- Needed only if your app uses Bluetooth scan results to derive physical location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
...
```

you can check more details here [source.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Comment: Tried that, nothings work. i still got "lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH" . i already mention that links didn't work in those 2 devices

Comment: i could make it work by adding the permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH  runtime