# java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10457 / PID 24525 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth

Android app giving:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10457 / PID 24525 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

When I try to connect with Bluetooth printer using BluetoothDevice().connect() in Xiaomi android 12

I am trying to connect with Bluetooth thermal but am not able to do it in android 12

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71552331/666228

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add user-permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

And then your codes, you have to check if the user is using Android 12. If yes, check the permission Bluetooth. And then you can able to use the Bluetooth.

Example here I use library from here. https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

```
private void checkPermissionBluetooth() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        final ArrayList<String> listPermission = new ArrayList<>();
        listPermission.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
        listPermission.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);

        Dexter.withContext(Kpp02NewActivity.this).withPermissions(listPermission).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
                threadBluetoothEnable();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

            }
        }).check();
    } else {
        threadBluetoothEnable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
permissions are granted

Comment: @ashimsaini have you checked the permissions at runtime as suggested by Ticheraz?

Comment: yes @MichaelKotzjan i checked. every permission is allowed

Comment: @ashimsaini I am facing a similar issue with Vivo devices, did you find any solution?

Comment: I could make it work by adding android.permission.BLUETOOTH permission runtime